# Elasticsearch delete document with id returns timeout

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, routes, sharding

I have a problem about my index. Some document of this index cannot be deleted.

I can get the document with :

```
GET /my_index/my_type/FXN5gs9QRk-xS3ag8RxmZg?routing=12345
```

but I cannot delete it with:

```
DELETE /my_index/my_type/FXN5gs9QRk-xS3ag8RxmZg
```

and with this one too :

```
DELETE /my_index/my_type/FXN5gs9QRk-xS3ag8RxmZg?routing=12345
```

When I tried to delete it returns 504 Time Out.

And also I cannot add new document with the same routing.

PS:
ElasticSearch Version : 1.4
Doc Count in that type: More than 400,000,000 
6 shards and 3 replicas

EDIT :

I cannot even add new document with this routing.

Comment: i found my solution by myself :). one of shards was broken, so data cannot bu updated. after delete and reallocate  that shard problem was fixed.

Answer (score 3):

You need to specify the routing value in the delete too.  Once you index documents with a custom routing value, you "take control" of where documents are placed.  ES won't know where to find it unless you provide the routing every time:

`DELETE /my_index/my_type/FXN5gs9QRk-xS3ag8RxmZg?routing=12345`

Although the timeout might be a different issue, since you should simply get a "File Not Found" style exception (or worse, if you haven't made routing required, deleting an unrelated document).

Comment: i actually i tried this one but it did not work for me. and i added one more porblem to  ask : i cannot even post new document with this routing . response is 504 again.

Comment: Thank you! This was driving me nuts.